# Are there command line arguments to import and setup projects for Eclipse + EGit?

Tags: android, eclipse, command-line, egit

Problem is this:
I'm using Android Development Tools (Eclipse with Android plugin), I have a git repo with lots of projects. However, for me and my team's purposes, we only need to import some of the projects in the repo.

Everyone before I join the team has to struggle with selecting the right projects, so I figure I'd try and write a script to automate this.

Is there any command line prompts that would do what that Import > Projects from Git wizard would do?

Feel free to tell me RTFM, provided you could point me to where the manual is. I couldn't find it on EGit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have checked in the `.project`, `.classpath`, and other project configuration files (which is highly recommended), you can use a Team Project Set to easily import a set of projects into any workspace. [Here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-cvs-project-set.htm) is the link in the Eclipse Help; it talks about CVS but applies to any SCM tool that you're using. The gist is:

1. Make sure you have the desired projects checked out into your workspace.
2. Select the projects you want, right-click, and choose **Export...**
3. Select the **Team Project Set** wizard.
4. Complete the wizard.

That will produce a `.psf` file that can then be used to import those projects from your SCM tool (git, svn, cvs, etc) into another workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a command line for this.

However you can use 'Export > Team > Team Project Set' to create a 'project set' (.psf) file. Other team members can use 'Import > Team > Team Project Set' to import that set of projects using the .psf file.